# Is the amount invested in stock by a company public information when more than 5%?

Tags: stocks

Say a large business such as Apple buys 10% of CitiBank. Is that public information? If so, where can that information be found?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the US, shareholders owning 5% or more of a public company must file a "beneficial ownership" report. In addition, transactions involving shareholders holding 10% or more must be disclosed. All these can be found in the [SEC database](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search-and-access). See [here](https://www.sec.gov/education/smallbusiness/goingpublic/officersanddirectors) for details.

These are SEC rules, so they only apply to companies listed as publicly traded in the US. In other countries rules may be different.